# Запятые в словосочетании "неизвестно, что приготовит мне"

Tags: пунктуация

Неизвестно, что приготовит мне.
Перед "что" стоит запятая потому, что "неизвестно" здесь является предикативом? Верна ли моя логика?

Comment: Не могу представить, где такое словосочетание может встретиться!

Comment: Артем, предложение либо не полное(пропущено какое -то слово), либо автор вопроса неправильно  выразился.

Comment: Это лишь кусок из предложения, там действительно пропущено слово.

Comment: @Артём Луговой *Не могу представить, где такое словосочетание может встретиться!* - представить дело не хитрое. "Мне он приготовил неприятный сюрприз: сказал, что я уволен" - "Неизвестно, что приготовит мне."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Перед "что" стоит запятая потому, ...неизвестно" здесь является предикативом?

В любом случае - не поэтому. Тут еще спорно, что "неизвестно" вообще предикатив. Но даже если трактовать так, то из этого факта необходимость запятой не следует.

В том виде, как предложение написано, его можно трактовать как СПП с придаточным "что приготовит мне", тогда запятая понятна. "Неизвестно" тут выступает как главная.

Если же трактовать как "неизвестно что" как "нечто", то запятая не нужна, "неизвестно" - наречие. При желании можно, наверное, даже как вводное слово трактовать. Все зависит от контекста. Но по крайней мере два случая представляются вполне реальными.

***- "Мне он приготовил неприятный сюрприз: сказал, что я уволен" 
- "Неизвестно, что приготовит мне."***  (в роли сказуемого, запятая перед придаточным )

***- "Мне он приготовил известно что" 
- "Неизвестно что [он] приготовит мне."***
(наречие, запятой нет) - трактовка по Кузнецову)

(+)

Оба имеющихся на данный момент ответа как минимум неполноценны. Второй случай не упомянут вообще.

Comment: Это вводное-то слово хамство?

Comment: @Niemand На хамство не отвечаю

Answer (score 0):

Перед ***что*** стоит запятая, потому что дальше следует придаточное предложение.